# Apple certificates, any way to submit to iTunes without being an Agent?

Tags: iphone, app-store-connect, iphone-developer-program

I know only agents can generate distribution profiles to submit to iTunes, my question is, is there a way for a non-agent with a certificate generated in an agent account to submit an app to iTunes?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if this helps you, but, I can submit to iTunes with:

- Distribution profile from my agent.
- Private key from my agent.

Comment: Do you mean the private key from the developer certificate?

Comment: The private key from the distribution certificate

Comment: Sorry meant to say distribution, looks like I will have to share that with one of my developers then. Thank you.

Comment: Generally when you are signing the app, that involves the archive step previosly to submission.